# Julia: Plugging Matrix Values into a Function

Tags: vector, julia

I have a given matrix PC1, which is a 3xn matrix. I would like to write a loop that calculates the magnitude (vector magnitude) of each line of our given matrix and rewrite it into a 1xn matrix. For magnitude I made the function:

```
function magnitude(x,y,z)
  sqrt((x^2)+(y^2)+(z^2))
end
```

I want to be able to use this function if possible to again calculate the magnitude of each line of my matrix. I have tried the following:

```
for j in size(pc1[:,1])
 B[j] = magnitude(pc1[1,j],a[2,j],a[3,j])
end
```

When I try this, I get an error reading:
"ArgumentError: Invalid index: 0.0 of type Float64"

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error as well as make my for loop work would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `B = LinearAlgebra.norm.(eachcol(pc1))` (explanation: uses `norm` from `LinearAlgebra` package. broadcasts the `norm` function over iterator `eachcol` going over `pc1` columns)

Comment: I think that should be `eachline(pc1)`

Comment: @MikaelÖhman, `eachline` is for reading text from streams. `eachcol` is the right function here.

Comment: Good idea to use standard library functions when possible, since most of the edge cases have been handled. Compare `magnitude(1e300, 1e300, 1e300)` with `norm([1e300, 1e300, 1e300])`.

Comment: @DNF Sorry, i meant `eachrow`. `eachcol` is of course definitely wrong here.

Comment: I believe `eachcol` is correct. The OP is just a bit sloppy in the description and MWE, but it's clear from context that it should be`eachcol`.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can do this:

```
#Suppose that my_mat is:
julia> my_mat
3×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.146247  0.309755  0.0802212  0.810787   0.459134
 0.810021  0.876092  0.89679    0.238271   0.852003
 0.124778  0.590032  0.613531   0.0857502  0.524727

julia> function magnitude(x...)
           x1, x2, x3 = x
           @show x1, x2, x3
           sqrt((x1^2)+(x2^2)+(x3^2))
       end
magnitude (generic function with 1 method)

julia> magnitude.(eachrow(my_mat)...)
(x1, x2, x3) = (0.14624718982068596, 0.8100214466524703, 0.1247777052693978)
(x1, x2, x3) = (0.30975515637837503, 0.8760918202600901, 0.5900319505173406)
(x1, x2, x3) = (0.08022117017277575, 0.8967900297662494, 0.6135309351302954)
(x1, x2, x3) = (0.8107874182293756, 0.23827052138513005, 0.08575020171498149)
(x1, x2, x3) = (0.45913420665189597, 0.852002514985355, 0.5247268441565018)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.8325217476436908
 1.1007374060423891
 1.0895356818360262
 0.8494128419174967
 1.1009317718358742
```

As you can see, you don't need a for loop for this, and broadcasting can do what you need through the dot (`.`) operator.
But maybe you ask why I used `eachrow` and how I'm accessing each column through the `eachrow` function. Well, let's see an example to understand what's happening inside `magnitude.(eachrow(my_mat)...)`:
The `eachrow` function returns a generator that iterates over the first dimension of the vector or matrix. Let's say I have a matrix named mat:

```
julia> mat = rand(2,2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.541733  0.0644034
 0.451938  0.612991
```

Now `some_func.(eachrow(mat)...)` is equivalent to these:

```
julia> some_func.([0.541733, 0.0644034], [0.451938, 0.612991])

# Which is equivalent to

julia> [some_func(0.541733, 0.451938),
        some_func(0.0644034, 0.612991)
       ]
```

And this is how I managed to broadcast your function on each column using broadcasting.

## Additional Notes

But I suggest you make your function robust and not limit it to specific dimensions (your function accepts three elements, which is usable only when you have a 3xn matrix). Let's make it better:

```
julia> function magnitude(x...)
           sqrt(sum(x->x^2, x))
       end
magnitude (generic function with 1 method)
```

One of the beautiful features of the `sum` function is that it can accept a function as its first positional argument and an iterable as its second positional argument; In this way, `sum` applies the given function on each element of the given iterable and then sum the results up. And now I apply it on `my_mat` through broadcasting:

```
julia> magnitude.(eachrow(my_mat)...)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.8325217476436908
 1.1007374060423891
 1.0895356818360262
 0.8494128419174967
 1.1009317718358742
```

The result is similar to before but not limited to a specific dimension!